# Record and Read an image file in the database . Using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

How can i record an image file to database and read it from database with MYSQL and PHP ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try to Google this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes a very basic example:

**MySQL**

```
CREATE TABLE 'picture' (
  'id' INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'image' LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
)
```

**PHP**

```
$image = file_get_contents('myimage.jpg');
// your db connection code here..
mysql_query("INSERT INTO picture (image) VALUES ('$image');
```

Bare in mind storing images in the database is not a very good plan. It is better to keep the images in a directory and just save the path in the database.

Comment: Correct. Then to display the image, create a PHP file and have it grab the `image` column from `picture` then just echo it out. But don't forget to change the content type, `header("Content-type: image/jpg");` but you'll need to determine which type of image it is in order to set the right one

Comment: Can u tell me why keep the images in a directory and save the path in the database is better than storing images in the database ?
Thanks

Comment: Database storage is usually more expensive than file system storage;

You can super-accelerate file system access with standard off the shelf products for example, many web servers use the operating system's sendfile() system call to asynchronously send a file directly from the file system to the network interface. Images stored in a database don't benefit from this optimization;

It is more complex to manage integrity between db metadata and file system data.